# Which photo more accurately represents Flaps 1 in a 737-800?

Tags: flaps

A recent update in a sim craft changed the visuals from what I'm used to, but from my research it looks to be more realistic.

This picture depicting it being more extended:
[image: This picture depicting it being more extended]

or this picture depicting almost no flap movement:
[image: this picture depicting almost no flap movement]

[This Aviation.SE post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34246/is-it-normal-to-take-off-with-limited-flaps-on-a-b737) clearly reflects the more extended option being more realistic - but can anyone confirm that that is how it looks on a flaps 1 setting in real life?

Comment: What sim is this?

Comment: @RonBeyer probably x-plane if it's a stock 737 model

Comment: The bottom photo looks to me about like a clean wing (no flaps extended), while the top photo looks more like a Flaps 1 or Flaps 5 configuration.  Note that Flaps 1 is an uncommon takeoff setting in the 737-800 due to the increased risk of a tailstrike. Flaps 1 is common on the 737-700 on long runways, while the -800's and -900's generally use Flaps 5 or greater for takeoff.

Comment: Given the current state of the Zibo mod, you can assume the older version to be more accurate than the newer one. If you want one with the best flight model, you should not use one that's newer than the end of April 2018.

Comment: And which view do you as the pilot see when flying the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

From a 737-800 today:

During takeoff, Flaps 5:

[image: 737-800 wing trailing edge with Flaps 5]

After initial flap retraction, to Flaps 1:

[image: 737-800 wing trailing edge with Flaps 1]

Conclusion: The first image in the question is a reasonable Flaps 1 depiction (more so than Flaps 5), and the second image is not a reasonable Flaps 1 depiction. It may not be a perfect Flaps Up depiction if there is the slightest misalignment in the trailing edges, but it certainly isn't a good depiction of Flaps 1.

Source: own photos.

Comment: It seems that you're right; but, respectfully, how do you know that this is a retraction from flaps 5 to 1 (instead of 10 to 5, or 5 to 2).

Comment: Because he was the pilot and is such a devoted contributor to ASE that he was running back and forth from the cockpit to the window to take pics--

Comment: I was deadheading on that flight, and it occurred to me right before takeoff to grab the photos for this exact thread. For the long runway being used, Flaps 5 is the only takeoff configuration our performance software would return. On flap retraction, there was the first retraction (to Flaps 1), the normal pause as acceleration happens, and then the retraction to the Flaps Up configuration. For a departure from a shorter runway, initial T/O flaps might be 10 or 15 or 25, and in a -700  aircraft then a Flaps 1  takeoff would be possible, but this was a Flaps 5 takeoff.

Comment: As to the Flaps 2 part of the question, we don't use Flaps 2 for takeoff (although the -200's could, and perhaps the -300's -- not certain about the latter) in the NG fleet. It's also not a stop on the retraction schedule - having started at Flaps 5 (or gotten there from a higher flap setting, 10 > 5, 15 > 5, 25 > 15 > 5), the next steps are to Flaps 1 and then to Up. Since I was deadheading on my own airline, I'm familiar with the procedures & flap retraction schedule being used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score -2):

On the 737, flaps 1 actually means leading edge slats only and no trailing edge flaps.

Therefore the first photo is ***definitely wrong***, while the second one is ***probably correct*** (since the slats cannot be seen).

Comment: This is incorrect. Selecting Flaps 1 on a 737 does indeed extended the trailing edge flaps.

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong. The TE flaps **do** extend at Flaps 1 on a 737.

Answer (score -2):

1 is the answer to this question: [image]

and
[image: image 1]

they are both the same

Comment: How do you know that’s flaps 1?

Comment: @MD88Fan The question is, which one **more accurately** shows Flaps 1. The picture with zero trailing edge flap extension is absolutely the WRONG answer. Even if the first picture shows, say, a Flaps 2 extension, it's still more accurate than the other.

Comment: The other two answers are wrong; this answer is correct.

Comment: Hey @hieverybody, welcome to Aviation.SE! please look carefully - the flap angle is different in both images. Even if it was the same, I do not see how it implies that 1 is the correct answer...

Comment: @AdityaSharma The question is either/or... which photo is a ***better*** depiction of Flaps 1.  **Your own post** shows that the second graphic in the OP is a nearly exact depiction of Flaps Up.

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure about 737-8, but for 777 flap 1 only slats move.
[image: Flaps sequence B777]

Comment: Very good find! Could you add the source though?

Comment: This photo is from my ground school material, I only have texture version which from our company B777 FCOM.

Comment: This is not true for the 737. See e.g. [here](http://www.b737.org.uk/flightcontrols.htm#Trailing_Edge_Flaps), flap position 1 moves the TE flaps.

Comment: Yeah, this is 777.... hahaha

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the stated (737) question, and the statement presented suggests the **wrong** answer. It might be better to edit or delete this answer.